# I'm trying to redefine the plain pagestyle as empty

Tags: header-footer

I tried to use this command, but doesn't work.

```
\makeatletter
    \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

I put it in the beginning, in the middle and just before the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: If you set the pagestyle to plain `\pagestyle{plain}` you should then get the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
\usepackage{nopageno}
```

Answer (score 4):

Page styles are merely a collection of macros which change the style of the page. Using

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

merely equates the two page styles in terms of what they do, but technically does not issue any page style. That is, you have to specify the page styles to be `plain` before they're actually changed. Therefore, also adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{plain}}
```

(anywhere in your preamble) should make all your pages be styled as `plain` (which is `empty`).